# I need to run 'netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disable' on powershell as administrator

Tags: python, powershell, administrator

I tried to open powershell as administrator and then use pyautogui to paste the command, but my mouse won't move after subprocess.
`output = subprocess.Popen(["powershell","-Command",'start-process PowerShell -verb runas']) time.sleep(2)  pyautogui.doubleClick((630,460)) pyautogui.typewrite('netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" enable')`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.